# Would that it were I or would that it were me?

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct?

> Would that it were I who contracted the disease, and not my 10-year-old son.

Or,

> Would that it were me who contracted the disease, and not my 10-year-old son?

Comment: Neither is correct. This is an archaic construction that nobody ever uses except to mock Victorian literature (or, even worse, to imitate it).

Comment: @JohnLawler: that's pretty categorical, I've just seen it used: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/445503/sentences-starting-with-would-that?noredirect=1#comment1070973_445503

Answer (score 2):

"Would that it were I who contracted the disease . . ." is grammatically correct.

The "would that it were" construction, however, sounds very formal--even stilted--to my ear. A more "natural" way of expressing the thought would be:

> "I wish I had contracted the disease, and not my 10-year-old son."

Moreover, the word *it* is not necessary, though it (i.e., the word *it*!) is certainly quite common. In my opinion, however, the indefinite it (i.e., the word *it*!) is frequently overused.

On the other hand, Charles Dickens began perhaps his most famous work, [*A Tale of Two Cities*](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/29595.html) as follows:

> "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of Light, it was the season of Darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair, we had everything before us, we had nothing before us, we were all going direct to heaven, we were all going direct the other way - in short, the period was so far like the present period, that some of its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good or for evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only."

Comment: Formal stilted, archaic or whatever, the phrase is perfectly correct and grammatical.

Comment: @Martin: No argument there.

Comment: Your Dickens quote is not relevant.  It does not have the word *would* in it.

Comment: @jwpat7: Point taken. Don